# Importing GeoJson into SQL Server table - always null?

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql, geospatial, geojson

I have the following code snippet: https://sqlfiddle.com/sql-server/online-compiler?id=2c3141ea-3da2-4d60-8ee8-d7f75f57a159 (See MRE below)

A simple GeoJson file with Polygons (and MultiPolygons, but only Polygons in this example) - I am struggling to figure out why the column with the Geodata (Geometry) always comes up empty - what am I missing?

```
DECLARE @GeoJSON nvarchar(max) = N'{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              -3.564987562532224,
              40.292745296473385
            ],
            [
              -3.564987562532224,
              40.16285276280664
            ],
            [
              -3.4121841156292874,
              40.16285276280664
            ],
            [
              -3.4121841156292874,
              40.292745296473385
            ],
            [
              -3.564987562532224,
              40.292745296473385
            ]
          ]
        ],
        "type": "Polygon"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              -3.3271182792090315,
              40.4031979514057
            ],
            [
              -3.3271182792090315,
              40.36480015317514
            ],
            [
              -3.1790407121077635,
              40.36480015317514
            ],
            [
              -3.1790407121077635,
              40.4031979514057
            ],
            [
              -3.3271182792090315,
              40.4031979514057
            ]
          ]
        ],
        "type": "Polygon"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              -3.2262995101188494,
              40.623560335315744
            ],
            [
              -3.297187707135521,
              40.623560335315744
            ],
            [
              -3.297187707135521,
              40.554176446403545
            ],
            [
              -3.2262995101188494,
              40.554176446403545
            ],
            [
              -3.2262995101188494,
              40.623560335315744
            ]
          ]
        ],
        "type": "Polygon"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              -3.4610182069080224,
              40.50628355201741
            ],
            [
              -3.5303311106570447,
              40.50628355201741
            ],
            [
              -3.5303311106570447,
              40.46794459511571
            ],
            [
              -3.4610182069080224,
              40.46794459511571
            ],
            [
              -3.4610182069080224,
              40.50628355201741
            ]
          ]
        ],
        "type": "Polygon"
      }
    
    }
  ]
}'


CREATE TABLE ImportDataGeo (
    Id INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Geometry GEOGRAPHY,
    GeoType NVARCHAR(50)
);

-- Import the GeoJSON
INSERT INTO ImportDataGeo (Geometry, GeoType)
SELECT    
        geography::STPolyFromText('POLYGON (' + coordinates + ')', 3035).ReorientObject() AS Geometry,
        geometryType AS GeoType
FROM OPENJSON(@GeoJSON, '$.features')
        WITH (
                geometryType NVARCHAR(50) '$.geometry.type',
                coordinates NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.geometry.coordinates[0][0]'
        )

-- View the imported data
SELECT * FROM ImportDataGeo;
```

Comment: Well, `$.geometry.coordinates[0][0]` doesn't return a scalar value. As a starting point you'll probably want to use `coordinates NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.geometry.coordinates[0][0]' AS JSON` here and then reformat the value so that it's compatible for use with `geography::STPolyFromText('POLYGON ((...))')`, [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geography/stpolyfromtext-geography-data-type#examples)

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Makes sence, thx for the hint.  

I tried adding `AS JSON` and updateting with the following;  

`geography::STPolyFromText('POLYGON (' + CONVERT(nvarchar(max), JSON_VALUE(coordinates, '$[0]')) + ')', 4326) AS Geometry`  

But this only return the first value (Lat), and not the entire array and Lng values. My SQL skills are put a test here as to what would be the best way forward